# How many ways we can find out the strip of N spins contains m "Parallel Pair" out of which m1 of them are "Up Parallel Pair"?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, statistical-mechanics

Let us consider a one-dimensional strip containing 8 spins. Spins can be up or down. And spins can be arranged randomly. So the total number of different microstates possible is $2^8$ (Taking Periodic Boundary condition  i.e the last spin interacts with the 1st one). One microstate looks like something as:
[Random Microstate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZYqq.png). In the picture the blue spins are called up spins and the red ones are down spins. Now we call two consecutive spins as a pair. If the two consecutive spins have the same direction we call it as "Parallel Pair". Again if a "Parallel Pair" contains both the spins up we call it as "Up Parallel Pair".
So one "Up parallel Pair" is $\uparrow \uparrow$ and one "Down Parallel Pair" is $\downarrow \downarrow$.
 
So how many ways we can find out the strip of 8 spins contains 4 "Parallel Pair" out of which 2 of them are "Up Parallel Pair"?

Can you generalize the problem as: How many ways we can find out the strip of N spins contains m "Parallel Pair" out of which m1 of them are "Up Parallel Pair"?

I have computationally found out that if we denote the number of ways (finding out the strip of N spins contains m "Parallel Pair" out of which m1 of them are "Up Parallel Pair") as $C_{m,m1}^N$ then for N=8 we have the following values.
Click on the link.[For N=8, all coefficient values (the number of ways)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTbPx.png)

Comment: are we looking for exactly 4  "Parallel Pair" or at least  4 "Parallel Pair"? (for example, if all the spins are up, there can be 7 Parallel Pairs)

Comment: We are looking for Exactly 4 "Parallel Pair" out of which 2 are  "Up Parallel pair"

Comment: While it doesn't change the mathematical content, I imagine the underlying context is physical e.g. the 1D Ising model. So you may want to add more tags (e.g. physics, statistical-mechanics) so that people with experience in such problems will see it.

Comment: How many parallel pairs are in the microstate $\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\downarrow\downarrow$? Do you count the first four spins as two "up" pairs, or three?

Comment: The first four spins are counted as three "Up Parallel Pair" @David K

Comment: @Swarnadeep Seth: When you add the boundary condition that the first and last states interact, do you still count the microstate as having a "first" state? In other words, is a microstate equivalent to one that it can be rotated to (by rotation I mean shifting the last entry to the first, not flipping each state)? As an example, is $\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow$ equivalent to $\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow$, or should they be counted differently?

Comment: @ Jeremy Dover No they are two different microstates. In one microstate we will assume that the last spin is connected to the 1st one so that the number of pairs is same as the number of spins. Something like a circular ring. But $\uparrow \downarrow\uparrow \downarrow\uparrow \downarrow\uparrow \downarrow$ is not equivalent to $\downarrow \uparrow \downarrow\uparrow \downarrow\uparrow \downarrow\uparrow$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u(n,k,m)$ be the number of strings of $n$ spins ("microstates"), starting with an "up" spin, that have exactly $k$ "up parallel pairs" and $m$ "down parallel pairs". Define $d(n,k,m)$ to be the number of strings of $n$ spins ("microstates"), starting with a "down" spin, that have exactly $k$ "up parallel pairs" and $m$ "down parallel pairs". So the number we seek is $u(8,2,2) + d(8,2,2)$.

First, note that $u(n,k,m) = d(n,m,k)$. Take any microstate of length $n$ starting with "up" with $k$ up parallel pairs and $m$ down parallel pairs, and flip every state. The result is a microstate starting with "down" and having $k$ down parallel pairs and $m$ up parallel pairs. This process reverses showing the equality. Hence the number we seek is $2 u(8,2,2)$.

Let's note some obvious properties of $u(n,k,m)$. Clearly if $k+m > n-1$, then $u(n,k,m) = 0$, since the string on $n$ states contains only $n-1$ possible parallel pairs. Moreover, if $k+m = n-1$, $u(n,k,m) = 0$ unless $k=n-1$ and $m=0$, in which case the microstate consists of $n$ up spins, and all pairs are up parallel pairs. Finally, for convenience we will define $u(n,k,m) = 0$ if $k<0$ or $m<0$.

So suppose $0 \le k < n-1$, $0 \le m$ and $k+m < n-1$. Every microstate of length $n$, starting with an "up" spin and having $k$ up parallel pairs and $m$ down parallel pairs, must have at least one down spin (since $k < n-1$). Let's count the number of such microstates where the first down spin in the microstate occurs at position $f+1$, meaning $f$ can vary between $1$ and $n-1$.

If the first down spin is at position $f+1$, then the first $f$ spins are all ups, and we have $f-1$ up parallel pairs in the string already. The remaining $n-f$ spins in the microstate form a string with $n-f$ spins, starting with "down", containing $k-(f-1)$ up parallel pairs and $m$ down parallel pairs. There are $d(n-f,k-f+1,m)$ ways to pick such a string, or alternatively, $u(n-f,m,k-f+1)$. Hence, we have the following recurrence for $u(n,k,m)$:
$$u(n,k,m) = \displaystyle \sum_{f=1}^{n-1} u(n-f,m,k-f+1)$$

Calculating out with the recurrence, we find that $u(8,2,2) = 9$, so the number of strings the OP requested is $18$. We can also use this terminology to state an "answer" to the more general problem, namely $u(N,m1,m-m1)+u(N,m-m1,m1)$.

I don't see an easy way to get a closed form for this, and I'm out of proofs for the day, but there are some interesting patterns in these numbers. Some searching on OEIS suggests that $u(n,k,0) = {{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1+k}{2}\right\rfloor}\choose{k}}$ (see http://oeis.org/A046854).

There are also some interesting patterns on the diagonals for fixed $k+m$. Examples:

- $k+m=n-2$: $u(n,k,n-2-k) = 1$ for $0 \le k \le n-2$. This one isn't that hard to see...there can only be one transition from up to down, so the microstate has to be $k+1$ ups followed by $n-k-1$ downs.
- $k+m = n-3$: $u(n,k,n-3-k) = k+1$ for $0 \le k \le n-3$.
- $k+m = n-4$: Seems to yield the sequence at http://oeis.org/A003991

ADDENDUM: Details on the calculation of $u(8,2,2)$

For small $n$, we can simply enumerate strings to find these are the only non-zero values for $u(n,k,m)$ for $n \le 4$:

- $u(1,0,0) = 1$
- $u(2,0,0) = 1$, $u(2,1,0) = 1$
- $u(3,0,0) = 1$, $u(3,1,0) = 1$, $u(3,2,0) = 1$, and $u(3,0,1) = 1$
- $u(4,0,0) = 1$, $u(4,1,0) = 2$, $u(4,2,0) = 1$, $u(4,3,0) = 1$, $u(4,0,1) =1$, $u(4,1,1) = 1$, and $u(4,0,2)=1$

To calculate $u(8,2,2)$ via recursion, we have
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
u(8,2,2) &=& u(7,2,2) + u(6,2,1) + u(5,2,0) \\
&=& u(6,2,2) + u(5,2,1) + u(4,2,0) + \\
&& u(5,1,2) + u(4,1,1) + u(3,1,0) + \\
&& u(4,0,2) + u(3,0,1) + u(2,0,0)\\
&=& u(6,2,2) + u(5,2,1) + u(5,1,2) + 6
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Using the recursion again gives us:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
u(8,2,2) &=& u(5,2,2) + u(4,2,1) + u(3,2,0) +\\
&& u(4,1,2) + u(3,1,1) + u(2,1,0) +\\
&& u(4,2,1) + u(3,2,0) +6\\
&=& u(5,2,2) + 9\\
&=& u(4,2,2) + u(3,2,1) + u(2,2,0) + 9\\
&=& 9
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

Comment: Is the recurrence relation correct? Or it will be $u(n,k,m)=\sum_ {f=1}^{N-1} u(n-f,m,k-f+1)$ @Jeremy Dover

Comment: Oh, dear...apologies for the typo. I will edit. The calculation is correct, though.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. May I ask you to show the calculation to find out 2*u(8,2,2)=2*9=18 ? Because according to my computational derivation it is coming out to be 36. And here you do not use the periodic boundary condition i.e the last spin and the 1st spin of the string form a pair , though your calculation is alright for the non-periodic case. And please check the computational table that I have given.

Comment: It is difficult to show a recursive calculation, but I will try by editing my answer. Apologies for not addressing the periodic case, I think I wrote down an older version of the question.

Comment: Thank you very much for doing the explicit calculation. For non-periodic boundary condition, your result matches with the computational value.

Comment: Could you please explain the logic behind $u(n,k,0) = {{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}+\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor}\choose{k}}$ . Because for $u(3,1,0) ={{\left\lfloor\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right\rfloor}\choose{1}}$=2 but it is not true. Practically $u(3,1,0)=1 $($\uparrow\uparrow\downarrow$). Similar case happens for $u(4,2,1) $also.

Comment: Shoot! Miscopied the syntax. It should be ${\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor + \lfloor\frac{k}{2}\rfloor}\choose{k}$. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Darn it! That's not right either. Let me take a minute to get my indices correct, and I'll re-edit. OEIS is not clear whether its sequence is 0- or 1-based.

Comment: OK, I've got it now. The OEIS sequence is 0-based, which was throwing me off. The correct value is ${\lfloor \frac{n-1+k}{2} \rfloor}\choose{k}$. I will edit appropriately.

Comment: @SwarnadeepSeth: The arguments are too long for this forum, but I'm pretty sure the answer you seek is $C_{m,m1}^N = 0$, if $N+m$ is odd, and $C_{m,m1}^N = u(N,m1-1,m-m1)+u(N,m1,m-m1) + u(N,m-m1-1,m1) + u(N,m-m1,m1)$, where $u$ is the function I defined above for the non-periodic case. There may be some index trouble in my translation to your notation...apologies in advance.

Comment: Two more comments: 1. In the above, the latter formula only holds if $N+m$ is even. 2. I confirmed the calculations for N=8 shown in the imgur attached to the question.

Comment: I have also checked that. It is working fine.